# Overridden function does not print base class data

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I am having an issue with the class inheritance in my code. Here is what I am doing: I have two classes, one called **Employee** and the second called **Manager**. **Employee** is the base class, it has a function that prints *Business card*, containing the name of the company and the function *name()*, that prints the name of the employee. Class **Manager** is a derived class and inherits (public: Employee). When I try to print the same business card for the manager, it does not display the name, only the company name. What could be the problem?
Below is the little snippet of, first, the Employee class:

```
class Employee {

public:
  // Constructor
  Employee(const char* name, double salary) : _name(name), _salary(salary) {}
  Employee() : _name(" "), _salary(0) {} // default constructor
  // Accessors
  const char* name() const { return _name.c_str() ; }
  double salary() const { return _salary ; }
  // Modifyers (if needed)
  double set_salary( double salary) { 
      _salary = salary;
      return _salary;
  }

  // Print functions
  void businessCard(ostream& os = cout) const {
    os << "   +------------------+  " << endl
       << "   | ACME Corporation |  " << endl 
       << "   +------------------+  " << endl
       << "   " << name() << endl ;
  }

private:

  string _name ;
  double _salary ;

} ;
```

and, secondly, the Manager class:

```
class Manager : public Employee {

public:

// Constructors
Manager(const char* name, double salary, set<Employee*>& subordinates) : 
    _name(name), _salary(salary), _subs(subordinates) {}

...

// Accessors
const char* name() const { 
    string name;
    name += _name;
    name += " (Manager)"; 
    return name.c_str() ; 
}

void businessCard(ostream& os = cout) const {
    Employee::businessCard();
}

private:
    string _name ;
    double _salary ;
} ;
```

The problem, as I think, is in the **name()** function, because if I write it explicitly, it appears on the card, though it is not inherited.
Could anyone help?

Comment: Just an aside, you should avoid returning `name.c_str()`. The `name` string will be destructed at the end of your `name()` function, so consequently, the `c_str()` will not be valid either. Ideally, don't handle plain `char *` or `const char *` types directly, just use `std::string` as much as possible.

Comment: @dreamlax, yes I also like string more as a working type, but my exercise was asking for const char* only, so I have to obey! Thanks and hello to New Zealand!

Comment: name and salary should not be redefined in manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Employee::businessCard();` it will call `const char* name() const { return _name.c_str() ; }` of `Employee` class. But earlier during the construction of the `Manager` object, you haven't passed name to the base class `Employee`, so it's not set in `Employee` class and you got it empty while printing.

So to make it work, it should be something like

```
Manager(const char* name, double salary, set<Employee*>& subordinates) : Employee(name,salary), _subs(subordinates)
```

and remove `_name` and `_salary` member variables from manager as it defeats the purpose of inheritance in this example.

Comment: Thank you!!! It solved it! I knew that I had to use the name and salary from Employee class and declare it in the constructor, but didn't know how.
I was simply reintroducing the variables in "private", writing over them, right? :)

Comment: If this answer solved it, please consider voting it appropriately. :)

Comment: it doesn't allow me, I could only "accept the answer"  as a forum novice.. :(